# Cannot connect to sql server from WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, odbc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unixodbc

I am attempting to get Ubuntu 22.04 to talk to mssql server on my Windows machine. The same machine hosting the WSL2 Ubuntu distro. I have installed unixodbc. The odbc.ini file is as follows:

```
[MYDSN]
Driver="ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"
Server=192.168.1.100
Port=1433
Database=mydb
```

My odbinst.ini file looks like this:

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

When I execute sudo odbcinst -j I get the following:

```
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

However, when I execute:

```
isql -v MYDSN sa "mypassword"
```

I get the following:

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I am able to ping the IP address of SQL Server. I have port 1433 open on the Windows firewall and SQL Server is setup to allow remote connections and is using TCP/IP.

Comment: You only state you have installed `unixodbc`, have you installed `msodbcsql18`?

Comment: You are correct that I failed to include that msodbcsql18 has been installed. The answer is yes, that it has been installed and the line in the odbcinst.ini: Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1 points to the correct location of the driver.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the quotes from `Driver="ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"` in your `/etc/odbc.ini` file yet?

Comment: I originally had it without the quotes and then added the quotes to see if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

In my troubleshooting I failed to go back and remove the quotes from the following:

```
Driver="ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server”
```

in the `odbc.ini` as suggested by AlwaysLearning.

Once I removed the quotes, I received a different error:

> [08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

This was fixed by adding `Encrypt=no` to the `odbc.ini` file. I found the answer to this issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/connection-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver16). I can now connect to SQL Server using iSQL.